# Inserted SD card isn't shown in nautilus

Tags: mount, sd-card

The SD card reader (*integrated in Dell Latitude E6540*) is shown after `lspci` and with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` I can see the output when inserting.

But `ls -la /dev/sd*` does no showing a change when a card is inserted or not.

And nautilus shows nothing from the SD card.

Output of `lsblk`:

```
sda                       8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   731M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                    8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                    8:5    0   465G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt          253:0    0   465G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 464,1G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
mmcblk0                 179:0    0   958M  1 disk  
└─mmcblk0p1             179:1    0 957,9M  1 part
```

And output of `cat /proc/partitions`:

```
major   minor    #blocks name
   8        0  488386584 sda
   8        1     748544 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5  487634944 sda5
  11        0    1048575 sr0
 253        0  487632896 dm-0
 253        1  486596608 dm-1
 253        2     999424 dm-2
```

Do I have to mount it?
Is there an option I have to enable?

Thank you.

Comment: Please insert SD card and add output of `lsblk` to the question.

Comment: Added. But I can see no entry for SD card?

Comment: SD card is at `/dev/mmcblk0`. Please add output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` to the question.

Comment: (German, but translated by me:) `fdisk: /dev/mmcblk0 can not be opened: Input-/Output-Error`

Comment: Are you sure that SD card is working correctly? Did you tried to insert it into other laptop or device to get confirmation?

Comment: Yes, on another laptop it works. And I used it in an audio device to record tracks in the morning, too.

Comment: Then try with different SD card reader. For example USB.

Comment: Okay, I do not have one. But I can try to lend me one. Why? To check if that SD card is readable by the laptop?

Answer (score 2):

check the partition:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

If you see partition of your sd card, you have to mount it.

```
sudo mkdir /media/your_sd
sudo mount /dev/your_sd /media/your_sd
```

Comment: Added to the question above. What does `dm` and `sr0` stand for? Thanks and welcome to the community!